# If $F : Ab \rightarrow Ab$ is an additive functor and $0 \rightarrow A \rightarrow B \rightarrow C \rightarrow 0$ is an exact split sequence then ...

Tags: algebraic-topology, exact-sequence, functors

> If $F : Ab \rightarrow Ab$ is an additive functor and $0 \rightarrow A \rightarrow B \rightarrow C \rightarrow 0$ is an exact split sequence $\Rightarrow$ $0 \rightarrow FA \rightarrow FB \rightarrow FC \rightarrow 0$ is an exact split sequence.

**Split**:  Since $s: C \rightarrow B$ exists such that $ps = 1_C$ ($p: B \rightarrow C)$, it follows that $Fs : FC \rightarrow FB$ exists and $Fp \circ Fs = 1_{FC}$ by the definition of a functor.

**Exact**: I know I have to show that $\text{im $Fi$} = \ker Fp$ $(i : A \rightarrow B)$, but I'm having trouble figuring out a way to do this.

---

**Question (1) :** Is the proof I gave of the second sequence being split correct since I didn't use the fact that $F$ is an additive functor at all?

**Question (2):** Anyone have any ideas as to how to show this?

Comment: A few things you haven't used.  First, because the map is additive, it will preserve not just when a map is the identity, but also when a map is the zero map, so an exact sequence is mapped to a chain complex.  Second, the one sided inverse you have to your map $F(B)\to F(C)$ implies the map is surjective (why?).  Third, with a split exact sequence, you not only have a one sided inverse to $B\to C$, but also a one sided inverse (on the other side) of $A\to B$, and the existence of this map will imply the map $F(A)\to F(B)$ is injective.

Comment: Could you explain why $F(B) \rightarrow F(C)$ is surjective?

Comment: Would $p \circ i = 0_C \Rightarrow F(p \circ i ) = 0_{FC} \Rightarrow Fp(Fi) = 0_{FC} \Rightarrow Fp(Fi (FA)) = 0_{FC} \Rightarrow Fp(\text{im } Fi) = 0_{FC} \Rightarrow \text{ im } Fi = \ker Fp$ suffice?

Answer (score 1):

For a sequence $0\to A\to B\to C\to0$ to be split exact, it is necessary
and sufficient that morphism $B\to A$ and $C\to B$ exist, satisfying
a few identities together with the given maps $A\to B$ and $B\to C$.
Any additive functor will preserve these identities, so map the
split exact sequence to another one.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean?  I don't understand what you mean by "map the exact sequence to another one".

Comment: What are the identities that $B \rightarrow A$ and $C \rightarrow B$ must satisfy?  The only definition of an exact sequence that I know of is $\text{im} ( A \rightarrow B) = \ker (B \rightarrow C$) for every term in the sequence.

Comment: @OliverG See corrected version!

Comment: What do you mean by 'map the split exact sequence to another one'?  I see that $s : C \rightarrow B$ exists and $q : B \rightarrow A$ exist such that $ps = 1_C$ and $qi = 1_A$ and $Fp \circ Fs = 1_{FC}$ and $Fq \circ Fi = 1_{FA}$.

Comment: @OliverG Don't forget the identity for $1_B$!

Comment: What is the identity for $1_B$?

Comment: Something like $sp+iq$? (The $+$ is why you need the functor to be additive.)

Comment: Why can you assume that $sp + iq$ is defined since only $ps$ and $qi$ are said to be defined?

Comment: @OliverG That's why I said "something like ..."

Comment: I don't understand, is there a specific identity for $1_B$?

Comment: @OliverG Yes, and it is preserved by the functor $F$.

Comment: Can you write out the identity explicitly?  I don't understand how the two split identities and a third identity can show the exactness of the sequence.

Comment: I think it is $sp+iq=1_B$. Now I'm not sure of your nomenclature here, what the names of the maps are, and what exactly their domains and codomains, are, or whether you are writing compositions left-to right or right-to-left. But if $ps$ is a map from $C$ to $C$, isn't $sp$ a map from $B$ to $B$ ...?

Comment: In the question I defined $i:A \rightarrow B, p : B \rightarrow C, s : C \rightarrow B, q: B \rightarrow A$ and the functor is covariant.  But why is it that if $qi=1_A$ and $ps=1_C$ that $sp + iq = 1_B$?

Comment: @OliverG That's not true: you did **not** define $q$ in your question. Also it is not the case that $qi$ and $sp$ being identities means that $sp+iq$ is an identity. What is true is that the original sequence is split exact iff there exist $s$ and $q$ satisfying the three identities.

Comment: My mistake, I defined it in the fourth post of this answer.  But why is the identity $sp + iq=1_B$ true?  And why does those three identities being true imply that the sequence is exact?

Comment: One is aiming to set up inverse isomorphisms $\Phi:A\oplus C\to B$ and $\Psi:B\to A\oplus C$. Write these putative isomorphism in terms of maps between $A$, $B$ and $C$. For $\Phi\circ\Psi$ and $\Psi\circ\Phi$ to be identity maps one needs a bunch of identities to hold.

Comment: What is a putative isomorphism?

Answer (score 0):

For the first question, we need the additivity. In fact, apply the functor $F$ to the sequence, then you have
$F0 \rightarrow FA \rightarrow FB \rightarrow FC \rightarrow F0$. So the question is, why do we have $0$ and not $F0$? This comes from the additivity of $F$ because $F$ sends the zero function on the zero function. So there is no problem to write $0$.

PS : my first answer here, excuse my English.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is nice to use [splitting lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splitting_lemma) here. It tells you that a split short exact sequence $$ A\to B \to C$$ is equivalent to
$$ A\to A\oplus C \to C  $$
where the maps are the inclusion are projection.

It is easy to see that such sequences sequences are always split short exact.

So what you need it hat additive functors preserve splittings and direct sums with its inclusion/projections. The first thing is easy since any functor preserves splittings.(As you said correctly) For the second part it depends on your definition of additive. (Preserving biproducts is [equivalent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Additive_category#Additive_functors) to be additive)